# Laravel Ajax Search

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, search, laravel-5

I am trying to create a search form, which searches for a record in a database table while the user is typing into the search field.

---

**Controller**

```
public function search() {
    // get the search term
    $term = Input::get('term');

    // search the members table
    $members = DB::table('members')
                ->where(concat("members.member_first_name,' ',members.member_last_name"), 'LIKE', "$term")
                ->orwhere(concat("members.member_last_name,' ',members.member_first_name"), 'LIKE', "$term")
                ->orwhere(concat("members.member_name_affix,' ',members.member_last_name,' ',members.member_first_name"), 'LIKE', "$term")
                ->orwhere(concat("members.member_first_name,' ',members.member_name_affix,' ',members.member_last_name"), 'LIKE', "$term")
                ->orwhere('members.member_first_name', 'LIKE', "$term")
                ->orWhere('members.member_last_name', 'LIKE', "$term")
                ->orWhere('members.member_business_address', 'LIKE', "$term")
                ->get();

    // return the results in JSON format
    return response()->json($members);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('search', 'mitgliederverzeichnisController@search');
```

**View**

```
<!-- THE SEARCH FORM -->
<form method="GET" id="search-form">
    <input type="search" id="term" name="term" onkeyup="ajaxSearch()" placeholder="Search the members table..." autofocus>
</form>

<!-- THE AJAX FUNCTION -->
 <script>
     function ajaxSearch() {
         $.ajax({
             url: 'search',
             type: 'GET',
             data: {term: $('#term').val()},
             dataType: 'JSON',
             success: function(response) {
                 console.log(data);
             }
         });
     }
 </script>

<!-- THE RESULTS TABLE -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="resultTableWrapper">
    <table id="resultTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Business Address</th>
                <th>Join Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
     </table>
 </div><!-- /#resultTableWrapper -->
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <p id="search-info">Please type your search phrase in the field above.</p>

<!-- USE THE JSON RESPONSE TO FILL THE RESULTS TABLE -->
@if (isset($_GET['term']))
    @foreach ($members as $member)
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>
                    {!! $member->member_name_affix.' '.$member->member_last_name.' '.$member->member_first_name.' '.$member->member_title !!}
                </strong><br><br>
                <div class="unhighlight">
                    {!! $member->member_business_position !!}<br><br>
                    {!! $member->member_business_name !!}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class='unhighlight'>
                @if ($member->member_private_address)
                    <span>
                        {!! $member->member_private_address !!} <br>
                        {!! $member->member_private_zip_code. ' ' .$member->member_private_location !!}
                    </span><br>
                    <div class='clear'></div>
                @endif
            </td>
            ... and so on ...
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

---

The error message I am getting when I start typing the letter 'a' into the search field:
`GET http://localhost.local/search?term=a   500 (Internal Server Error)`

---

I am very new to laravel and I would be very thankful for any kind of help!
**UPDATE** 
Thanks to amieiro I managed to figure out that the error seems to be with the Input::get() method:
[image]

Comment: Internal server error usually means that you messed up something in your code. Check your laravel storage/logs folder or apache logs for hints on what it is.

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, I can only find .gitignore files in the logs folder.

Comment: You should check body of ajax response. It would have more information what is wrong. You can inspect it in developer tools. You can look at this [example](http://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art034) for Chrome.

Comment: Actually error is within your `where` clause you cannot use `concat` function in `where` clause in order to use `concat` you need to use `whereRaw('concat("members.member_first_name,' ',members.member_last_name" LIKE ?',array("%$term%"))`

Comment: @yariash Thank you for pointing that out. I updated my answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can inspect the error trying to see the JSON. In Google Chrome you can see it inspecting the element, reloading the page and then in the Network tab, XHR filter. You can see it in the next image

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out! I updated my answer accordingly!

Answer (score 2):

As per your update you need to include `Input` within your controller simply using

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Input;
```

at the top of the file after namespace. Instead of using `Input` facade you can use [**`Request`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests) facade for better coding standards

Comment: I get 'Class Input' not found if I do that.

Comment: I got the Input part to work now, thank you! `public function search(Request $request) {
$term = $request->input('term');`

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote if it really helped you. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your query like this, in `where` or `orWhere` first param shuould be column name also add `%` around `$term` and remove unnecessary where conditions.

```
public function search(Request $request) {
$term = $request->input('term');
$members = DB::table('members as m')
            ->where('m.member_first_name', 'LIKE', "%$term%")
            ->orWhere('m.member_last_name', 'LIKE', "%$term%")
            ->orWhere('m.member_business_address', 'LIKE', "%$term%")
            ->get();
return response()->json($members);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did that it did not change anything though. I am still getting the same error message.